# Stokes' Theorem which boundaries to integrate

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have a couple of questions regarding Stokes' Theorem.
Stokes' Theorem states $$\int \int_S (\nabla \times \textbf F) \cdot d\textbf S = \int _{\partial S } \textbf F \cdot d \textbf s$$

$1)$ If I wanted to calculate the total of flux from a surface which resembles a pair of pants ($3$ empty holes) Would it suffice to just parametrize any one open hole and integrate it or would I have to parametrize each hole, integrate them and finally add them all up? I am fairly certain that if the holes were covered with a circular surface I would need to parametrize each hole and add them up.

With this being said, I think it would suffice to parametrize just one hole and integrate it, otherwise the flux with the empty hole and covered hole would be the same.

$2)$ If I had to calculate the flux of a surface that is a cylinder with a semi-sphere attached to it at one end of the cylinder; would I need to parametrize the bottom of the cylinder (where the semi-sphere is not attached) and parametrize the intersection of the semi-sphere/cylinder then add up their integral? Or would I be able to parametrize just one or the other? How would this change if the bottom of the cylinder was filled in vs empty?

If anyone can clear this up for me, that would be amazing. I've been having trouble with this for a while and been trying to look for similar problems online but I haven't been able to.(They usually only have one boundary)

Edit: Just need help with this last one now. If I had a cylinder with base and lid, if I used the boundaries to calculate flux, wouldn't it always be zero? Because the boundary for the cylindrical part and the base/lid are shared, but will have opposite orientation(surface should always be on the left side) and therefore cancel to get zero

Comment: What do you mean by "covered hole"?

Answer (score 1):

To answer both questions: $\partial S$ really means the *whole* boundary of the surface $S$, and $S$ really means the *whole* surface $S$. If you pick and choose parts of the boundary or parts of the surface to parametrise, then you're integrating over a different region.

If $S$ is a surface built up from two smaller surfaces $S_1$ and $S_2$ such that $S_1$ and $S_2$ only intersect at a curve, then the integral over $S$ of a function is equal to the sum of the integrals over $S_1$ and $S_2$. This means that if you have a cylinder with a base but no lid, you need to parametrise the cylindrical part and the base, integrate over both and add them together.

Likewise, if $\partial S$ consists of three separate curves, you need to integrate over each curve and add them together.

Comment: Thanks. Just one more question, if I had a cylinder with base and lid, if I used the boundaries to calculate flux, wouldn't it always be zero? Because the boundary for the cylindrical part and the base/lid are shared, but will have opposite orientation(surface should always be on the left side) and therefore cancel to get zero. Thanks again!